# Is there a built-in way to cast to a different underlying type but preserve const qualifiers?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, constants, c++17

Does the C++11/14/17 standard library have a way to cast an object to a different type but with the same cv-qualifiers as the original object? E. g.

```
char* ptr;
const char* cptr;
```

`type_cast<void*>(ptr)` should yield the type `void*`
`type_cast<void*>(cptr)` should yield the type `const void*`

Comment: So you are not satisfied with compile-time failure in case of wrong modifiers, like with `static_cast`?

Comment: Why do you need to cast `Bar` to `Foo` explicitly?

Comment: @DanM.: yes, exactly. This is for templated code. I don't want to fail, I want to return the correct type based on the argument's cv-qualifiers.

Comment: There is no such cast built into the language. Though you could write your own using a combination of `std::is_const`, `std::add_const_t` and `std::remove_const_t`.

Comment: @Slava: because in the actual code the cast is between unrelated types. I used compatible types here purely for illustration and simplification.

Comment: I am afraid you oversimplified your case and it became meaningless. You better make more realistic example.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe when why not just overload based on the argument's cv-qualifiers?

Comment: @Slava The example seems fine to me.

Comment: @DanM.: at the very least because it duplicates otherwise exactly identical code.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: thanks. That's what I was afraid of. I didn't know about `std::add_const`, by the way, only `is_const`.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe you can use `if constexpr` to greatly reduce duplication.

Answer (score 3):

Not in the standard library, but it is certainly possible to implement it yourself:

```
namespace detail_base_type_cast {
    template <class In, class Out>
    struct copy_cv {
        using type = Out;
    };

    template <class In, class Out>
    struct copy_cv<In const, Out &> {
        using type = Out const &;
    };

    template <class In, class Out>
    struct copy_cv<In volatile, Out &> {
        using type = Out volatile &;
    };

    template <class In, class Out>
    struct copy_cv<In const volatile, Out &> {
        using type = Out const volatile &;
    };
}

template <class Out, class In>
typename detail_base_type_cast::copy_cv<In, Out>::type
base_type_cast(In &obj) {
    return obj; // Implicit derived-to-base conversion
}
```

Comment: Has anyone tested this? g++ says: `expected nested-name-specifier before ‘detail_base_type_cast’`.

Comment: @RabidBear yup, that was an embarrassing typo... I fixed it, however it also looks like OP changed their question shortly after my original answer. Thus this solution does not interact with pointee constness as the new question requires.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like there is no C++17 or earlier stdlib way to do what you want in single function/statement.
However it looks like there might be something like this in C++20: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_reference (not available in any of the compilers yet it seems).

EDIT: but it's available in Ranges lib so if you already use it, you can use `ranges::common_reference_t` instead.

But for your use case, either overloading on argument constness or using `if constexpr` might be a better option.

I.e. something like:

```
template<typename T>
auto foo(T &bar) {
    // lots of code

    if constexpr(std::is_const_v<T>) {
        return static_cast<const Foo&>(bar);
    } else {
        return static_cast<Foo&>(bar);
    }
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/dbCUdM

Comment: I don't see how `common_reference` helps with my question, could you elaborate?

Comment: it gives you the common reference, just as it says. I.e. reference that can be used to refer to both (or more exactly - all provided) types, so if one of them is `const` it'll also be const. See: https://godbolt.org/z/X5Zfc3

Comment: The question also applies to pointers, but `common_reference` only applies to base types and reference types.

Comment: @JonHarper it was edited after I've made my comment. Nevertheless, it's trivial to turn reference into pointer. I.e. `common_pointer` could be defined as something like `add_pointer_t<common_reference_t<...>>`.

Not sure what's with all "quiet" down-votes.